# Collapsing Bootstrap Responsive Navbar Earlier

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, blogger

Hello I'm using a responsive navbar with bootstrap in my blogger blog.
My problem is, that it is piling up very ugly beore the point is reached where it does collapse.

I tried to overwrite the media query, but now the result I get is a constantly triggered navbar, which covers up my blog and the trigger button is nowhere to be seen.

That's what I wrote. Any idea how I can get it to work?

```
@media screen (max-width: 1200px){
  .nav-collapse {
    clear: both;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse.in .btn-group {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: none;
    float: none;
    max-width: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before,
  .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .navbar-form,
  .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .nav-collapse,
  .nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .navbar .btn-navbar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

My Navbar HTML:

```
<div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'>
  <div class='container'>

    <button class='navbar-toggle pull-left' data-target='.navbar-responsive-collapse' data-toggle='collapse' style='z-index: 25; border:0;' type='button'>
      <span class='icon-bar'/>
      <span class='icon-bar'/>
      <span class='icon-bar'/>
    </button>

    <div class='nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
              <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com'><i class='icon-home'>&#160;    </i>Home</a></li>
              <li class='dropdown'>
                <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><i     class='icon-info-sign'>&#160;</i> About <b class='caret'/></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/p/kreatief.html'><i     class='icon-exclamation'>&#160;</i>KreaTief</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/2013/05/faq.html'><i class='icon-question'>&#160;</i>F.A.Q.</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/p/archiv_7.html'><i class='icon-archive'>&#160;</i>Archive</a></li>

              <li class='dropdown'>
                <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><i class='icon-edit'>&#160;</i>Tutoriallists <b class='caret'/></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/p/code.html'><i class='icon-code'>&#160;</i>Code</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/p/picture.html'><i class='icon-picture'>&#160;</i>Picture</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/p/food.html'><i class='icon-food'>&#160;</i>Food</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/p/diy_28.html'><i class='icon-puzzle-piece'>&#160;</i>DIY</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/p/other.html'><i class='icon-folder-open'>&#160;</i>Other</a></li>
                  <li class='divider'/>
                  <li class='dropdown-header'>Tutorials By Level</li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/search/label/%E2%9C%A4?max-results=10'>&#10020;</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/search/label/%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4?max-results=10'>&#10020;&#10020;</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/search/label/%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4?max-results=10'>&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/search/label/%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4?max-results=10'>&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/search/label/%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4%E2%9C%A4?max-results=10'>&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;&#10020;</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/p/contact_23.html'><i class='icon-comments'>&#160;</i>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href='http://kreatiefdesigns.blogspot.ch/'><i class='icon-cog'>&#160;</i>KreaTief designs</a></li>

              <li class='dropdown'>
                <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><i class='icon-eye-open'>&#160;</i>Follow <b class='caret'/></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  <li><a href='http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/feeds/posts/default'><i class='icon-rss-sign'>&#160;</i>RSS</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/en/blog/3645972'><i class='icon-plus-sign'>&#160;</i>Bloglovin&#39;</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://blog-connect.com/a?id=1589905134039127183'><i class='icon-anchor'>&#160;</i>Blogconnect</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
              <li class='dropdown'>
                <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><i class='icon-paper-clip'>&#160;</i>Find Me <b class='caret'/></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                  <li><a href='http://bloggerlooks.blogspot.ch/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>Blogger Goodies 4 U</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://mynimi94.deviantart.com/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>DeviantArt</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://pinterest.com/mkreatief/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>Pinterest</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://bp.cplove.de/mitglieder/myri/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>Blogosphera</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://www.hierschreibenwir.de/user/12356/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>HSW</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://myriamfrisano.blogspot.ch/'><i class='icon-external-link'>&#160;</i>Wortgefängnisarchitektur</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
            </ul>
<!-- Search Field -->
<div class='pull-right navbar-search'>
<form action='http://www.google.co.uk/cse' id='cse-search-box'>
<input name='cx' type='hidden' value='014092313708849156193:r0xlcl-xk10'/>
<input name='cof' type='hidden' value='UTF-8'/>
  <input class='form-control search-query span3' id='q' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='text'/>
  <i class='icon-search'/>
</form>
      </div><!-- /search container -->
    </div> <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Can you post your navbar HTML too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could go to the [Bootstrap customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables) and change the variable for the width that the navbar collapses at `@navbarCollapseWidth`

This is a screenshot of its location on the Bootstrap 2.3.2 page, but you can do a similar thing with Bootstrap 3.0 as well. They just name it differently.

[image: Bootstrap 2.3.2 navbar collapse width]

You do that and hit the download button at the bottom, and use that bootstrap.css file instead of the default one and everything should be good.

Comment: Yeahy! Thanks! That's even simpler. Didn't realize there was a customization page.

Comment: If you're using the nuget less package for Bootstrap 3 you can change the variable @grid-float-breakpoint, but be aware of overwrites on updates.